# PC waking up from standby on its own exactly one time?

Tags: windows, sleep, wake-up, standby, peripherals

Both my personal and work laptop (working from home currently) wake up on their own just seconds after I put them into standby for the first. After that, the standby works just fine without the PC waking up again on its own. Also at every standby after the first, the PCs can be woken up as normal/intended via either pressing any key on the keyboard or moving the mouse.

Since this happenes with both laptops, I'm guessing it has something to do with the docking station or maybe some peripherals. One of them is using Win10, the other Win11. Peripherals present are currently a Logitech keyboard, mouse and webcam, all connected via the docking station via USB-C.

Trying to figure this out on my own, neither `powercfg -lastwake`, `powercfg -requests` or `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` yielded any results whatsoever. And I mean literally nothing, not even when waking it up via keypresses or mouse movements. `powercfg -lastwake` for example just spits out `Wake History Count - 0` and `Wake Source Count - 0`

How would I go about diagnosing why this is happening?

Comment: Anything in the System Event Log?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thought of that aswell at first, but I honestly have to admit I'm a bit overwhelmed by the Event Log. Is there anything in particular I should look out for?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe Mode and going into standby?

Comment: @DrDecane Look for events around the time of the standby/wakeup

Comment: If both of these devices only do so when connected to said network, packet sniffing might also yield interesting results. Look for magic packets. iirc there could be differences between a fully cold boot and standby mode regarding WOL. The puzzling part is where they only do it once though.